# Reading SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

I am calling a method that returns XML (SimpleXMLElement) as a response. However, no matter how I tried, I cannot read the XML variable, the variable is named $response.
Attached you can see the structure of the XML variable, that displays when I peak to it. [Variable structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny0Et.png)

When I converted the XML to string using

```
> (string) $response
```

I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<responseImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.fio.cz/schema/responseImport.xsd"><result><errorCode>1</errorCode><status>error</status><sums><sum id="EUR"><sumCredit>0</sumCredit><sumDebet>50</sumDebet></sum></sums></result><ordersDetails><detail id="1"><messages><message status="error" errorCode="2001">Message here</message></messages></detail></ordersDetails></responseImport>
```

I need to get the errorCode. I tried to query the value using code:

```
$response->xml->result->errorCode;

$response->result->errorCode;
```

And many other ways, but never was successful. Do you know how could I get the value? 
Thank you in advance!

---

UPDATE: 
None of the answers actually worked, but they were helpful anyways. Thanks to your answers, I was able to construct the right code.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$errorCode = (string) $xml->result->errorCode[0];
```

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this or do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$result = $xml->xpath('//responseImport//ordersDetails//message[@status="error"]/@errorCode');
echo 'error code: ',$result[0],"\n";
```

Output:

```
error code: 2001
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a case of following all of the layers of data to get the error code, so

```
echo (string)$response->ordersDetails->detail->messages->message['errorCode'];
```

will give

```
2001
```